# Save file in oracle

Tags: php, oracle, blob

I have a following code that make a file:

```
  $imagem = base64_to_jpeg( $iten->file->content,  'saida.'.getB64Type( $iten->file->content ));
  $tamanhoImg = filesize($imagem);
  $mysqlImg = addslashes(fread(fopen($imagem, "r"), $tamanhoImg));

// unlink($imagem);

  $values[2] = $mysqlImg;

  $teste = $osController->inserirAnexo( $values );
```

The file was made succefully and I would like save this file in oracle database that has the field `BLOB` type

```
public function inserirAnexo( $values ){
        require_once "class.connection_factory.php";
        $con  = new connection_factory();
        $conn = $con->getConnection();
        $retorno = false;

        $sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE_PIC VALUES (:p0,SEQ_SEEQUENCIA.NEXTVAL,:p1,:p2)";
     //   $valor1 = bin2hex( base64_decode( $values[2] ) ) ;

        try{
            $stmt = ociparse( $conn,$sql );
            oci_bind_by_name( $stmt, ":p0", $values[0] );
            oci_bind_by_name( $stmt, ":p1", $values[1] );
            oci_bind_by_name( $stmt, ":p2", $values[2] );
            $retorno = oci_execute( $stmt, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS );

        }catch (PDOException $e){
            echo "Erro: ".$e->getMessage();
        }

        return $retorno;
    }
```

The value `:p2` is field with the a image file.

When I try save in database show the following message:

> Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-01465: invalid hex number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html), page 233 "Inserting and Updating LOBs". Here's the example from that page:

```
<?php
$c = oci_connect('hr', 'welcome', 'localhost/XE');
$myblobid = 123;
$myv = 'a very large amount of binary data';
$s = oci_parse($c, 'insert into mybtab (blobid, blobdata)
                    values (:myblobid, EMPTY_BLOB())
                    returning blobdata into :blobdata');
$lob = oci_new_descriptor($c, OCI_D_LOB);
oci_bind_by_name($s, ':myblobid', $myblobid);
oci_bind_by_name($s, ':blobdata', $lob, -1, OCI_B_BLOB);
oci_execute($s, OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT); // Don't commit so $lob->save() works

$lob->save($myv);
oci_commit($c);
$lob->close(); // close LOB descriptor to free resources
?>
```

And the accompanying description:

> The `RETURNING` clause returns the Oracle LOB locator of the new row. By binding as OCI_B_BLOB, the PHP descriptor in `$lob` references this locator. The `$lob->save()` method then stores the data in `$myv` into the BLOB column. The OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT flag is used for `oci_execute()` so the descriptor remains valid for the `save()` method. The commit concludes the insert and makes the data visible to other database users. If the application uploads LOB data using a web form, it can be inserted directly from the upload directory with `$lob->import($filename)`. PHP’s maximum allowed size for uploaded files is set in php.ini using the upload_max_filesize parameter.

Comment: Saved. But if I look at field blob in database, for example de image, dont't show, only in Hex format and in text the name of file with the extension.

Comment: Verify that you are creating a valid JPG with `base64_to_jpeg`.  Write the result to disk and check the file can be opened correctly.

Comment: Was created because the file was saved in a folder

Comment: This command works: `$imagem = base64_to_jpeg( $iten->file->content,  'saida.'.getB64Type( $iten->file->content ));`

Comment: I don't know about this:  `$mysqlImg = addslashes(fread(fopen($imagem, "r"), $tamanhoImg));`

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't make much sense.  It'll corrupt the file. Try `$values[2] = file_get_contents($imagem);` instead.

Comment: Great! Solved! I'll find how recover hahaha. Please add as answer